# Assembly security

Tags: security, assembly

I'm currently offering an assembly compile service for some people. They can enter their assembly code in an online editor and compile it. When then compile it, the code is sent to my server with an ajax request, gets compiled and the output of the program is returned.

However, I'm wondering what I can do to prevent any serious damage to the server. I'm quite new to assembly myself so what is possible when they run their script on my server? Can they delete or move files? Is there any way to prevent these security issues?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Guess what happens when someone posts the source code for a virus!

Comment: Run it in a one-off throw-away VM that doesn't mount any fs from the host and does not have any network, or just automatically re-image the box after each run :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the assembly is involved. Surely you're not going to let the resulting program run on your server?

Comment: Yes, the resulting program is going to run on the server. That's why I'm worried about the security. I'm currently looking for an VM as someone in the comments suggested :)

Comment: Does anyone have a good tutorial on how to set up such a virtual machine in Linux? I'm searching, but I can't find any :(

Comment: There's a lot of services like that - codepad.org, ideone.com, etc, you could search for design considerations of such services.

Comment: In assembly _everything_ can be done. That's because there is an almost 1 to 1 mapping between assembly and machine code, and ultimately every computer is executing machine code. And there is some low level hardware magic which can _only_ be done in assembly. So the security risk is the highest possible of all languages possible.

Comment: First of all, you really should specify your OS in the question explicitly. It's the OS function to enforce security of resources and programs that are using them. Next, I don't know the exact setup for Linux, but basically you want to run your program in a restricted process or from a restricted user account. You have to configure it in such a way that your process cannot access the file system (except, perhaps, a throw-away temporary directory created for it), network, other processes, etc. It should be able to do console I/O, though.

Comment: @drhirsch, No. A program can't do "everything", just because it's written in assembly. (How should user account security work if that were true?) Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode.

Comment: @noah1989: I didn't mean "everything" in the sense of "everything possible" but in the sense of "everything all possible programs in every language can do". I am aware of the fact that even an assembler program can not do the impossible, I may b old but I am not _that_ stupid ;-)

Comment: @drhirsch: I just meant that the "low level hardware magic", which might be only possible in assembly is not a security issue per se because that definitely requires ring 0 privileges, which a regular process just doesn't have. But indeed in assembly there are no language-provided security features as in higher level (especially scripting) languages, so you must rely on the operating system's security.

Comment: @noah1989 just use your favourite privilege escalation exploit then..

Comment: hm.. why not use an x86 emulator? heck there is even one written entirely in javascript: http://bellard.org/jslinux/tech.html -- run this on node.js and you're done :D *Edit:* seems like someone already had this idea: https://github.com/tlrobinson/node-jslinux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/libsandbox/. It is designed for doing exactly what you want on a linux server:

> This project provides API's in C/C++/Python for testing and profiling simple (single process) programs in a restricted environment, or sandbox. Runtime behaviours of binary executable programs can be captured and blocked according to configurable / programmable policies.
>
> The sandbox libraries were originally designed and utilized as the core security module of a full-fledged online judge system for ACM/ICPC training. They have since then evolved into a general-purpose tool for binary program testing, profiling, and security restriction. The sandbox libraries are currently maintained by the OpenJudge Alliance (http://openjudge.net/) as a standalone, open-source project to facilitate various assignment grading solutions for IT/CS education.

Comment: Heh, yeah, you really wouldn't want some enterprising young students writing code that would give them correct answers to all the problems, or hose everyone else's scores. Or doing any other sort of nefarious things to the system.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a tutorial service, so the clients just need to test miscellaneous assembly code and do not need to perform operations outside of their program (such as reading or modifying the file system), then another option is to permit only a selected subset of instructions. In particular, do not allow any instructions that can make system calls, and allow only limited control-transfer instructions (e.g., no returns, branches only to labels defined within the user’s code, and so on). You might also provide some limited ways to return output, such as a library call that prints whatever value is in a particular register. Do not allow data declarations in the text (code) section, since arbitrary machine code could be entered as numerical data definitions.

Although I wrote “another option,” this should be in addition to the others that other respondents have suggested, such as sandboxing.

This method is error prone and, if used, should be carefully and thoroughly designed. For example, some assemblers permit multiple instructions on one line. So merely ensuring that the text in the first instruction field of a line was acceptable would miss the remaining instructions on the line.

Comment: The important thing here is that the instructions should be whitelisted - anything that's not explicitly allowed should be... well, not allowed :) Otherwise you end out forgetting to blacklist that one command that allows them <insert exploit here>.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling and running someone else's arbitrary code on your server is exactly that, arbitrary code execution.  Arbitrary code execution is the holy grail of every malicious hacker's quest.  Someone could probably use this question to find your service and exploit it this second.  Stop running the service immediately.  If you wish to continue running this service, you should compile and run the program within a sandbox.  However, until this is implemented, you should suspend the service.

You should run the code in a virtual machine sandbox because if the code is malicious, the sandbox will prevent the code from damaging your actual OS.  Some Virtual Machines include VirtualBox and Xen.  You could also perform some sort of signature detection on the code to search for known malicious functionality, though any form of signature detection can be beaten.

This is a link to VirtualBox's homepage: https://www.virtualbox.org/

This is a link to Xen: http://xen.org/

Comment: If the code is run on the under a restricted user account on a decent OS, arbitrary code execution should not be a problem. I cannot gain root access or circumvent file system and other resource limitations on a linux machine, even if I can write and execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Gaining root accesses and circumventing file system limitations may not be the only detrimental things that can happen.  That's kind of a naive approach to security.

Comment: There are computer systems that many users an use and run their own code on, for example in universities, and they can handle security quite well.

Comment: I went to a university where that happened.  And all of those machines were completely insecure for that reason.  "Handling security quite well" doesn't really mean anything.  When kids tested their server code almost every machine was exploitable.  I'm sorry but you can't really make the argument that arbitrary code execution is secure if you just have a decent OS.

Comment: Even if users are restricted to their own file system resources, they could set up an entry point and wait for, or even discover, a new zero-day exploit in the OS to escalate their privileges.

Comment: They might also be able to glean information about other user accounts and other seemingly innocuous information that could allow them to later gain control of a system.  There are so many variables in configuration that you cannot just rely on your OS.